# STOMP notification in spring not returning message in console

Tags: java, spring, websocket, push-notification, stomp

So I have been trying to write simple notification for my application and have the following problem. I was able to connect the websocket but it should also write the message in the console which it does not. I just started to learn websockets and notification 2 days ago, so I don't really understand how I should write correctly

My config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/all","/specific");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/ws").setAllowedOriginPatterns("*").withSockJS();
    }
}
```

controller:

```
@RestController
public class MessageController {

    @Autowired
    private MessageService messageService;

    @MessageMapping("/message")
//    @SendTo("/all/messages")
    public ResponseEntity<MessageResponse> sendMessageToAll(@RequestBody MessageRequest request) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(messageService.sendMessageToAll(request.getMessage()));
    }

    @MessageMapping("/message-user")
    public ResponseEntity<MessageResponse> sendMessageToUser(@RequestBody MessageRequest request) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(messageService.sendMessageToUser(request.getUser(), request.getMessage()));
    }
}
```

request:

```
@Getter
public class MessageRequest {
    String message = "mess";
    User user;
}
```

response:

```
public class MessageResponse{
        String message;
}
```

message model:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Message {

    private String message = "mess";
    private String recipient;
    private boolean isRead;

    @ManyToOne
    private User user;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Message{" +
                "message='" + message + '\'' +
                ", recipient='" + recipient + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

service and its implementation:

```
public interface MessageService {
    MessageResponse sendMessageToUser(User user, String message);
    MessageResponse sendMessageToAll(String message);
}
```

```
@Service
public class MessageServiceImpl implements MessageService {

    @Autowired
    private SimpMessagingTemplate messagingTemplate;

    @Override
    public MessageResponse sendMessageToAll(String message) {
        messagingTemplate.convertAndSend("/all/messages", "meessaaaa");
        return new MessageResponse();
    }

    @Override
    public MessageResponse sendMessageToUser(User user, String message) {
        messagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser(user.getUsername(), "/specific", message);
        return new MessageResponse();
    }
}
```

Just in case it will be needed, here is the test html with which I am checking my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>STOMP</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>STOMP test</h1>
<script crossorigin="anonymous"
        integrity="sha256-wS9gmOZBqsqWxgIVgA8Y9WcQOa7PgSIX+rPA0VL2rbQ="
        src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin="anonymous"
        integrity="sha512-iKDtgDyTHjAitUDdLljGhenhPwrbBfqTKWO1mkhSFH3A7blITC9MhYon6SjnMhp4o0rADGw9yAC6EW4t5a4K3g=="
        src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/stomp.js/2.3.3/stomp.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

  let url = ('ws://localhost:8080/ws/websocket')
  console.log(url)
  stompClient = Stomp.client(url)

  stompClient.connect({
  }, function () {
    stompClient.subscribe('/all/messages', function (output) {
      console.log(JSON.parse(output.body))
    });
  }, function (err) {
    alert('error' + err);
  });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Can anybody solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Currently in the sample which you have posted, there is no logic which sends message to `/all/messages` path automatically, so nothing is printed in console after websocket connection gets established. try sending some message to this path, or simply update your code with the following snippet to send one dummy message which in-turn posts message to `/all/message` path.

```
stompClient.connect({}, function () {
        stompClient.subscribe('/all/messages', function (output) {
            console.log(output.body);
        });
        stompClient.send("/app/message", {}, JSON.stringify({message: 'hello'}));
    }, function (err) {
        alert('error' + err);
    });
```